# Which is better, a class within a class or in a separate class altogether?

Tags: c++, class, subclass

This is the scenario.
I have a `Layer` class which I want to create a subclass of, let's call this `ParentLayer` class. The `ParentLayer` class will have yet another `Layer` subclass, called the `ChildLayer` class. Which is the best way to do it?

**Declare `ChildLayer` inside `ParentLayer` as a private class.**

```
// LayerSubclass.h
#include "Layer.h"

class ParentLayer : public Layer {
private:
   class ChildLayer : public Layer {
   private:
       // ChildLayer members
   public:
       // Stuff...
   };

   ChildLayer _childLayer;

public:
   // Stuff...
};
```

**Declare ChildLayer as a separate class within the same header file.**

```
// LayerSubclass.h
#include "Layer.h"

class ChildLayer : public Layer {
private:
    // ChildLayer members
public:
    // Stuff...
};

class ParentLayer : public Layer {
private:    
   ChildLayer _thisChild;

public:
   // Stuff...
};
```

I've been using the first method but then I thought of the second method (which is cleaner and much more readable). Thoughts?

Comment: If you have to ask, use a non-nested class, it's less complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might prefer to use a nested class:

- If the nested class need `friend` access to private members of the containing class (which for example may be true of iterator classes, which access members of the corresponding container class)
- Or if the nested class is a private implementation detail of the containing class, which is not exposed to other classes via the containing class' public API

Comment: `ChildLayer` does need access to some `ParentLayer` methods and functions but all of them are declared `public`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @LanceGray Prefer to use a non-nested class, unless you have some good reason to choose a nested class (needing `friend` access to another class' `private` members is IMO one reason to make it nested).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question of "what's better" but a question of what design fits your requirements. Without description of the problem that you're trying to solve no sensible answer can be given.

Comment: The `ChildLayer` class is only used by `ParentLayer` class and no one else. I was thinking whether using separate classes would be the best way of writing it instead of nested classes.